# Unexpected result of fromkeys method

Tags: python

I am new to Python and learning its basics.

I came across this piece of code:

```
keys = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' }
vowels = dict.fromkeys(keys)
print(vowels)
```

My expectation was that the output will be like:

```
{'a': None, 'e': None, 'i': None, 'o': None, 'u': None}
```

But when I executed this piece of code in pyCharm, I got the following as the result:

```
{'u': None, 'o': None, 'e': None, 'a': None, 'i': None}
```

Please help me to understand what is happening here. Is there any logic behind it?

Edit 1 (After initial comments on the question):

My understanding is the following:

1. when the dictionary 'keys' was created, the memory blocks would have been assigned in that sequence of keys, with the address of the next member block (like a linked list).
2. when the 'fromkeys' method will get executed, it will follow the same pattern and will get a clone.

Comment: hashtables (dictionaries) have no-sense or ordering. If you run this piece of code again you will get different results

Comment: `keys` is a set, and sets have no guaranteed order.

Comment: We should not expect any order of key -> value of a dictionary (map).

Comment: In recent versions of python, you can rely on insertion order. So if you turn `keys = {'a', ...}` to `keys = ['a', ...]` -- then you can get what you're expecting. Whether or not you need (or should rely on) the insertion order is a different question.

Comment: @UltraInstinct AFAIK, sets do not keep the insertion order; only dicts do.

Comment: @Norrius That was response to D. Seah's comment, actually (I should have tagged them). The second statement was for OP, as to how they could have their output by relying on this property. Sorry for the confusion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set` is not an ordered iterable object in Python. so when you iterate you get random item.

but when make keys as a `list` or `tuple` object you get what you want:

```
keys = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
vowels = dict.fromkeys(keys)
print(vowels)
#{'a': None, 'e': None, 'i': None, 'o': None, 'u': None}
```